# Migrate Windows Server c3.large (old generation) to t3.large

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I'm trying to migrate a Windows Server c3.large to t3.large. The first problem I faced is that t3 instances need to have ENA enabled where c3 doesn't.

So I get through this documentation following all the steps to update all drivers:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/migrating-latest-types.html

So the problem is when I've done steps 1, 2 and 3 I stop the instance and I go to the AWS dashboard and change type c3.large to t3.large. At this point the instance can not be started because ENA support is disabled, so I enabled it as this doc explains:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html

But once is enabled I can start the instance but I lose the connectivity with it, I can't connect, I can't even make a screenshot / nor access to the instance log from the aws dashboard.

I've read that it may be caused by a problem with the ENA kernel, have any of you faced this issue? Is something I'm missing?

Sincerely,